# Set initial screen orientation

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am making an app where the first screen I want to view is Portrait. I then go to the next activity which is set in landscape.

The problem i'm facing is that if I return to the first screen it will be set as landscape, evidently inheriting the orientation from the previous screen.

Is there a possible way to set the initial screen orientation as portrait which is set but the user can then go ahead and change it to landscape when they want?

Thanks

EDIT: SOLVED

Thank you for your suggestions. I've overcome the issue. It's slightly difficult to explain but will try my up most.

So my first activity has a feature whereby if the phone is turned to landscape it will show an image, full screen. And again, if the phone was portrait, the portrait view, where I have a list view.

The second activity loads an editing page to let me change that image.

So now if i press back on the editor activity. The first activity would load into a list view in LANDSCAPE. which is NOT what I want.

therefore in order to get around this. I have firstly disabled the back button when the first activity is landscape so the user can not remove himself from the view without turning the phone to landscape.

I then moved the code:

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //Show landscape picture
            }
    }
```

to the top of my class before the onCreate method.

This has solved my issue so that now, if I was to go back to my first activity whilst in landscape the only thing that would show is the landscape view.

I hope that was clear enough for all to understand :)

Again thanks for the help!

Comment: Happy with the question but not with the answer. Nobody knows another way to do that?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution for the exact same problem. So is there not a way to set the initial orientation of an Activity (as portrait for instance), but without overriding the android:screenOrientation="user" tag???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can set the screen orientation programmatically in the onCreate()- method:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

just right before the call of super.onCreate();.

I hope, I could help you.

Best regards,
G_J

Comment: Unfortunately that sets the view as portrait indefinitely. I did try this previously with a counter to say once the screen has been opened in the portrait orientation, allow the screen to be changed. when count > 0, but no luck just yet.

Comment: Okay...did you try to set it back to "ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR", when count>0? I think, this could solve it.
Here are the possible parameters for the setRequestedOrientation(int screenOrientation)- method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#screenOrientation

Answer (score 2):

You can change the orientation of individual activities using this in the manifest file of your application within each of your activity's tags:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

**with**  either

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

**OR**

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

as per your needs

Answer (score 1):

you can set the screen orientation programmatically in the onCreate() method:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

just right after the call of `super.onCreate();.`

OR

You can also specify the orientation in the Manifest file like this

```
<activity android:name="com.example.project.activity"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. I've overcome the issue. It's slightly difficult to explain but will try my up most.

So my first activity has a feature whereby if the phone is turned to landscape it will show an image, full screen. And again, if the phone was portrait, the portrait view, where I have a list view.

The second activity loads an editing page to let me change that image.

So now if i press back on the editor activity. The first activity would load into a list view in LANDSCAPE. which is NOT what I want.

therefore in order to get around this. I have firstly disabled the back button when the first activity is landscape so the user can not remove himself from the view without turning the phone to landscape.

I then moved the code:

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //Show landscape picture
            }
    }
```

to the top of my class before the onCreate method.

This has solved my issue so that now, if I was to go back to my first activity whilst in landscape the only thing that would show is the landscape view.

I hope that was clear enough for all to understand

Again thanks for the help!